# Div doesn't apply border-radius property

Tags: html, css, border

I have a `<div>` tag, on which I need a bottom border and border radius to be applied, but it won't work.

```css
.part2 {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 10%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 10%;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.part3 {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border-color: pink;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 10%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 10%;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="part2 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class="part3 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-t-40">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class="part4 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

So basically it shows up like that :

[image: border for part2]

So my problem is :
I have a page on my website, which contains many `<div>`. Each div as a .part1, .part2 etc.. class on them. I need the borders of each .partX div to have a curved border bottom. It works for the header, it works for .part4, but it doesn't work for .part3. That's the mystery, and I'm trying to solve it. I need to have the border of div.part3 curved, so I'm using border radius, but it doesn't work at all. Why ?

Above is the result of the css code I used. As you can see the border is straight, I need it curved.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just added clarification on the problem

Comment: Your code does NOT demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Try removing the `.home` selector from your CSS to show the problem.

Comment: Right, thanks ! I just modified the snippets !

Comment: So what isn't working now?

Comment: As you can see, there's border that works and another that doesn't. The first white div's bottom border doesn't work while the grey div border works, and I don't know why that happens. Edit : okay i changed the color of the background and it works, I guess I should check for it, sorry !

Comment: The white divs border is there....it's just *white*. Change it to something else and you'll see,

Comment: Sounds to me as though it's the **top** radius that actualy might be the issue and that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume there's some bad practices further up the style inheritance tree. Without seeing more of the layout to inspect it's hard to tell why one works and the other doesn't but I'd bet if you inspected them in the developer console and paid attention to the order of inception of the style classes you could find your culprit(s).

However, most of this could be consolidated;

```css
.part2, .part3, .part4 {
  border-width: 0; /* Not 0px */
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 10%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 10%;
}

.part2 {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.part3 {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border: pink 5px solid;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.part4 {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #0f0;
  border: orange 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="part2 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class="part3 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-t-40">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class="part4 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.